# Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null' java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback, spring-boot-starter

I want to use a common xml in my logback-spring.xml? how to include the xml in logback-spring.xml without getting an error. I got that to include an xml in our logback-spring.xml we need to use  but somehow this is not working for me. I have invested so much time but no results.
https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/the-logback-manual/content/en/chapter-3-configuration/configuration-file-syntax/file-inclusion.html

logback-common.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/${NAME}.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>


    <logger name="com.ms" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver" level="trace" additivity="true">
    </logger>
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan = "true">
    <property resource ="application.yml"/>
    <springProperty name="NAME" source="spring.application.name" /> 
    <include resource="logback-common.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Logbacking-service
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file which has to be used inside the logback-spring.xml must not contain the `<xml>` tag. The file should be like below. The `<included>` tag must be used in file which has to be loaded inside another file.

```xml
    <included>
            <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
            <property resource ="application.yml"/>
            <springProperty name="NAME" source="spring.application.name" />
            <appender name="Console"
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <Pattern>
                        %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
                    </Pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
            
            <appender name="RollingFile"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOGS}/${NAME}.log</file>
            <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
    
            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
                <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
         
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
    
        <logger name="com.ms" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
        
        <logger name="org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver" level="trace" additivity="true">
        </logger>
        
    </included>
```

Comment: doesnt't work. would you provide the final and full configuration?